# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I am trying to do lightweigh migration for my core database. I've included all the code in my appdelegate like is said in every tutorial. Then I have this piece of code.

```
- (void)fetchNewsIntoDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document
{
    dispatch_queue_t fetchNews = dispatch_queue_create("news fetcher", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchNews, ^{
        NSArray *news           = [GenkData getNews];
     [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{

        int newsId          = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in news) {
            newsId++;
            [News newsWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withNewsId:newsId];
            NSLog(@"news inserted");
        }

        [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
       }];
    });
   dispatch_release(fetchNews);

}
```

But when I run it, It runs it the first time correctly, but then when I refresh I get this error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: The error is pretty clear-- your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is not set up correctly. Show the code where you create it.